# Typeorm and operator without using querybuilder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

In NestJS / Typeform I want to make a query that sues to conditions as an `AND` condition.

I tried something like this

```
 async getByUniqueConstraints(user: User){
        const {email, phoneNumber} = user
        const foundUser = await this.userRepository.findOne({where: [email, phoneNumber], });

    }
```

The problem with this is that it uses an `OR` condition. Is there a way to use this with an `AND` operator instead without using a querybuilder or any more advanced concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` with fields in curly braces uses AND operator. You can see it in docs here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md